# Showing infimum of a set is smaller or equal to the infimum of a different set

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

Let $R= [a,b] \times [c,d]$ be an arbitrary rectangle.

Define $S_1 =\{f(x,y): (x,y)\in R\} $ and $S_2=\{f(x,y):a\leq x \leq b\}$

**Claim:** For every $c\leq y \leq d$ we want to show that $\inf(S_1) \leq \inf(S_2)$.

**My attempt:** Let $y_0 \in [c,d]$ be arbitrary.

I realized that by drawing a picture the set $S_2$ the infimum of it is the fixed $y_0 $ we let from the beginning. However, I am not sure how to formally prove this whether if its by definition or by some theorem. Please help, thank in advance.

Comment: Please help!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much, but if you don't mind could you confirm if this is correct set represeting $[a,b] \times \{y\}=\{(x,y): a \leq x \leq b,y = y\}$ I'm just not 100% sure whether if $y = y$ makes sense... Please and thanks!

Comment: What is the connection between $S_2$ and $y$s? Is $S_2 = S_2(y)$? Cause now it seems the claim should be exactly the opposite.

Comment: You need to consider how you've defined $S_2$. As $S_1$ and $S_2$ are currently written, you have $S_1\subseteq S_2$ (to see this more clearly, consider drawing a picture of the domain of $f$ as it pertains to $S_1$ and $S_2$). If you mean for the domain of $f$ as it pertains to $S_2$ to be a fixed horizontal line, then you should write something like $S_2(y_0)=\{f(x,y):a\leq x\leq b,\ y=y_0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

(1) You have the inequality backwards. For example  if the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R^2$ and $f(x,y)=y^2$ and $R=[0,2]\times [1,2]$ then $\inf S_1=\inf [1,4]=1>0=\inf [0,\infty)=\inf S_2=0.$

(2) $S_1\subset S_2$ so any lower bound for $S_2$ is also a lower bound for $S_1.$ That is, if $A$ is any lower bound for $S_2,$ then for any    $z\in S_1$ we have  $z\in S_2,$  so $z\ge A.$

So let $L$ be the greatest lower bound of $S_2$.Then $L$  is $one$ $of$ the lower bounds for $S_1,$ so the $greatest$ of the lower bounds for $S_1$ must be be at least $L$.

Comment: @Clayton. Thanks.  I have changed it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response so is $[a,b] \times \{y\} \subset [a,b] \times [c,d]$ wrong? This hint (from @Clayton) actually helped me solve the problem that I needed it to be solved. Maybe the claim I wrote was unclear is that the case?

Comment: The claim I made above I believe is correct, it should be $\inf(S_1) \leq \inf(S_2)$. I believe the inequality is not backwards I drew a picture to show that the claim makes sense. When we have for any $y\in[c,d]$ fixed the infimum of $S_2$ would just be at $y$. And infimum of $S_1$ would be below the above $y$.When we pick $y$ big enough (but smaller than $d$) then clearly for this $y$ the infimum of $S_1$ would be smaller. Say the infimum of $S_1$ is $c$ then we can always pick a $y > c$ and knowing that $y$ is the infimum $S_2$ we know $y>c$ from how we chose $y$ then our claim follows.

Comment: @javacoder: your claim is correct **if** you assume $y\in[c,d]$ is fixed. The way you have phrased it in the original post is not super clear about this, though. As it is defined, $S_2$ does not have a restriction on $y$ (meaning that $y\in(-\infty,\infty)$ as opposed to $[c,d]$).

Comment: I thought it was a mathematical/philosophical/logical convention that if quantifier of a "for all" statement was outside of a set it would imply that $y$ is "fixed" (or arbitrary as on paper it would look better). At least that's how I been taught. I would very appreciate if this topic can continue to be discussed will appreciate a follow up! @Clayton

Comment: Sure, @javacoder. The specific thing here is that you need $y\in[c,d]$. If you look at your definition of $S_2$, you make no such assumption. (Note: you make this statement in your claim, but we must look to the definition of $S_2$ to make sure we are working with the right thing).